# PHPUnit on Netbeans no tests executed

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I'm trying PHPUnit to work on my Netbeans 8.0.2. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I followed this documentation:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html

I've installed phpunit and it's skeleton generator, and followed through till step 5. But when I'm trying to test it, the test won't run. It always says "No tests executed." "Perhaps error ocurred, verify in Output Window."
I've checked the output window and it shows this:

```
"/usr/bin/php" "/usr/local/bin/phpunit" "--colors" "--log-junit" "/tmp/nb-phpunit-log.xml" "/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/php/phpunit/NetBeansSuite.php" "--run=/var/www/html/calculator/tests/calculatorTest.php"
PHPUnit 4.8.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

unrecognized option --run
Done.
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: It's telling you what the problem is, `--run` is not a valid option.

Comment: Then, what should I do? if `--run` is not a valid option then what should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a problem in NetBeans 8.0.2. I found two bugs in their Bugzilla system related to the `--run` parameter.

- [Bug 254221](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=254221)
- [Bug 254276](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=254276)

It has been fixed, but is only available in the nightly builds, since 8.0.2 is the most current release.

Answer (score 2):

Go back to PHPUnit 4.7, if you can.